# Instantiating mocks with Moq is insanely slow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Method under tests accepts `cell_provider` which is `Func<string, Cell>`, creates 625 instances of `Cell` class and calls `instantiate(Vector2)` on each instance.

There are 3 calls to the method inside the test, so `cell_provider` is totally called 1875 times

Test with this this `Func<string, Cell>` completes in **0.2s**

```
class DummyCell : Cell
{
    public DummyCell(string s):base(s)
    {
    }
    public Action<Vector2> on_instantiated;
    public override void instantiate(Vector2 position)
    {
        if (on_instantiated != null)
        {
            on_instantiated.Invoke(position);
        }
    }
    public override void destroy()
    {
    }
}
//...
Func<string, Cell> cell_provider = s =>
    {
      DummyCell res = new DummyCell(s);
      res.on_instantiated += v =>
       {
           min_x = min(min_x, v.x);
           max_x = max(max_x, v.x);
           min_y = min(min_y, v.y);
           max_y = max(max_y, v.y);
       };
      return res;
    };
```

This completes in **10 seconds**

```
Func<string, Cell> cell_provider = s =>
  {
      Mock<Cell> res = new Mock<Cell>(s);
      res.Setup(c => c.instantiate(It.IsAny<Vector2>()))
      .Callback<Vector2>(v =>
        {
            min_x = min(min_x, v.x);
            max_x = max(max_x, v.x);
            min_y = min(min_y, v.y);
            max_y = max(max_y, v.y);
        });
      return res.Object;
  };
```

I guess, it's because, I not only create a `Mock<Cell>` instance inside cell_provider, but also use `Setup`

Can I write something like this?

```
Mock<Cell> res = new Mock<Cell>(<I should put something here>);
res.Setup(c => c.instantiate(It.IsAny<Vector2>()))
  .Callback<Vector2>(v =>
    {
        min_x = min(min_x, v.x);
        max_x = max(max_x, v.x);
        min_y = min(min_y, v.y);
        max_y = max(max_y, v.y);
    });
Func<string, Cell> cell_provider = s =>
  {
      return res.<make_instance>(s);
  };
```

Comment: Why do you create 625 objects in your unit test?

Comment: The method of my class creates 625 objects internally. I create one object and run the method.

Comment: I cannot return the same instance in each cell_provider because the property, assigned by `Cell` constructor will be the same if I do so

Comment: But do you really **care** about property values of 625 different objects? It's pretty unusual for a unit test. A unit test usually verifies just one value, not 625.